# Do all J2ME phones support JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, gwt, java-me, mobile

Are there any J2ME phones that *don't* support JavaScript?

And are there generally limitations on the JavaScript that is supported / portions of the language that aren't implemented?

Comment: There is no correlation between J2ME (Java ) and javascript !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a great website for phones which support certain javascript/html features. Hopefully it can be helpful - http://www.quirksmode.org/m/table.html

Answer (score 4):

J2ME is a platform for Java, [not JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java).

While there are now several mobile browsers... and one mobile platform... with JavaScript support, to the best of my knowledge this is not in any way connected to J2ME.

Comment: sorry, my question is javascript in mobile browser

Comment: In that case, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274868/mobile-device-javascript-css-support-whats-out-there